# What MAC did SSLv3.0 use? How did it compare to HMAC in TLS 1.0 and above?

Tags: tls

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS):

> TLS has a variety of security measures:
>
> Using a message digest enhanced with a key (so only a key-holder can
> check the MAC). The HMAC construction used by most TLS cipher suites
> is specified in RFC 2104 **(SSL 3.0 used a different hash-based MAC)**.

What hash-based MAC did SSLv3.0 use?  How does it compare to the ubiquitous HMAC that is used everywhere else today?

Comment: And did you up read the wiki page to the SSL 2.0/3.0 sections?

Comment: @schroeder The section on SSL2.0 included this:  `SSL 2.0 had a weak MAC construction that used the MD5 hash function with a secret prefix, making it vulnerable to length extension attacks.` Didn't seem to mention a specific protocol.

Comment: And did you look up the RFC for the specifics? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6101

Comment: `The MAC is generated as:   hash(MAC_write_secret + pad_2 + hash(MAC_write_secret + pad_1 + seq_num + SSLCompressed.type + SSLCompressed.length + SSLCompressed.fragment))` -- but this doesn't answer the second question... how does this compare to HMAC, why is one better or worse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was concatenated in [SSL 3.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101):

```
    hash(MAC_write_secret + pad_2 +
         hash(MAC_write_secret + pad_1 + seq_num +
              SSLCompressed.type + SSLCompressed.length +
              SSLCompressed.fragment));
```

but XOR'ed in [HMAC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104):

```
    H(K XOR opad, H(K XOR ipad, text))
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. =) Can you speak to why the XOR is more secure than the concatenation, given the result is just going to be hashed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack is the vulnerability. It let attackers add extra data without invalidating the hash. Most modern hash algorithms aren't vulnerable to this, so eg KMAC doesn't need the double hashing of HMAC.

Comment: HMAC is a construction that is generic and secure. It also takes a key in most implementations, which could make a difference e.g. if you implement it using a HSM or other hardware device. Given the construction above, I don't see any *practical* length extension attack - the only thing that may be changed in size is the fragment, and that's double hashed.